# Change culture of site that is based on link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.NET 5 website where the culture is defined in the link. For example:

http://localhost:8080/nl/customers

http://localhost:8080/fr/customers

http://localhost:8080/en/customers

I need to implement a button to change the language. Is there a way to do this without having to parse the url and adding the language prefix myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper method

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string RouteToCurrent(this UrlHelper urlHelper, RouteData routeData, object routeValues)
    {
        // Create an IDictionary<string, object>
        var requestRouteData = new RouteValueDictionary(routeData.Values);

        var replaceValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        foreach (var value in replaceValues)
        {
            if (requestRouteData.ContainsKey(value.Key))
            {
                 requestRouteData[value.Key] = value.Value;
            }                    
            else
            {
                 requestRouteData.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
            }                    
        }

        return urlHelper.RouteUrl(requestRouteData);
    }
}
```

As parameters you pass current routedata and an anonymous object with keys and values you want to change.

```
@foreach (var lang in Model.LanguageList)
{
   <li>
       <a href="@Url.RouteToCurrent(ViewContext.RouteData, new {locale = lang})">@lang</a>
   </li>
}
```